# A more geometric proof that $\pi_1(S^1,x_0)\cong\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Hatcher proves that $\pi_1(S^1,x_0)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ by using $\mathbb{R}$ as a covering space for $S^1$ and using a life on cycles in $S^1$. Its a cool proof, but I'm kind of wondering if there is a more "geometric proof". I was thinking of something that basically argues that if $\gamma_1$ loops around once and $\gamma_2$ loops around twice, the only way to transform $\gamma_1$ to $\gamma_2$ is "unatttach" $\gamma_1(0)$ from $x_0$ and then "reattach" it at the end.

I guess one way to see this is that if you tried to not "unattach" it, then your loop would need to "move backwards" at some point, but I'm not sure how to make this argument more formal. Is this a wild goose chase or is there something here?

Comment: If you attempt to make this formal you end up just coming up with the covering space proof.  Keeping track of how much you have gone "forwards" or "backwards" is exactly lifting the loop to a path in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yeah, this is my intuition for the result, but formalizing that proof is hard without the notion of covering space. I know I’ve seen non-covering space proofs, but they go deep into the weeds.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Another proof uses van Kampen’s Theorem for fundamental groupoids, which is a natural generalisation for van Kampen’s theorem for fundamental groups. See https://people.math.harvard.edu/~hirolee/pdfs/231a-35-van-kampen.pdf for a great exposition.

Comment: @MarkSaving Right. The trouble is that such proofs are less geometric than the covering space arguments.